# How to use Newton-Raphson method to check differentiability of a function?

Tags: roots, newton-raphson

Let's say we have a function `f(x) = x^a + x^b + x^c` (a, b, c, x ∈ R)

How can we check the differentiability of f(x) first using the Newton-Raphson's method?

Using the formula to get iterations of approximate roots requires f'(x) but how can I first check the differentiability before I try to use the method? I know how to check its differentiability using other methods but I specifically want to know how one can use the Newton-Raphson method

Comment: You need differentiability to use Newton-Raphson. The differentiability of $f$ is guaranteed by the power rule.

Comment: @JohnDouma yes that would be specific to this function. But is there a way we can check for any function?

Comment: @Vens8 Differentiability is not something you can check numerically, regardless of the numerical method. You'll have to check that some other way *before* attempting to use a root-finding algorithm that requires differentiability, such as Newton-Raphson.